# How can I stop css translate from bringing the element to the front?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a created a table with some basic css to set the styling of it. No z-index or position properties are set anywhere, just colours, padding and margin.

I have implemented fixed column and row headers which help the user navigate large data sets which I have accomplished with the following code:

```js
document.getElementById("TableDiv").addEventListener("scroll", function() {

  // position row headers
  var horizontalTranslate = "translateX(" + this.scrollLeft + "px)";
  var rowHeaderCells = this.querySelectorAll(".RowHeaderCell");
  for (i = 0; i < rowHeaderCells.length; i++) {
    rowHeaderCells[i].style.transform = horizontalTranslate;
  }

  // position column headers
  var verticalTranslate = "translateY(" + this.scrollTop + "px)";
  this.querySelector("thead").style.transform = verticalTranslate;
});
```

```css
td {
  text-align: center;
}

th {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.RowHeaderCell {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="TableDiv" style="width:200px; height:180px; overflow:scroll;">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Heading 1</th>
        <th>Heading 2</th>
        <th>Heading 3</th>
        <th>Heading 4</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="RowHeaderCell">Row 1</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="RowHeaderCell">Row 2</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="RowHeaderCell">Row 3</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="RowHeaderCell">Row 4</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Now the exact issue I am having is that after the transform the row headers are being brought to the front of the UI and scrolling makes them overlap the column headers.

Before scroll:[image: Before scroll]

After scroll:[image: After scroll]

If i remove the above code that positions row headers then the levels are correct, which proves to me that this is caused by the row headers translate.

Without position row headers code:[image: Without position row headers code]

I have tried re-ordering the two translate chunks of code so it does columns first but the result is the same.

I have tried with translate() and translateX/translateY methods with the same result.

I have also attempted to solve this using the z-index and position css properties but have had no luck, the result is still the same.

I would be happy if there was another form of translate that would allow me to send it to the back after, or bring the column headers to the front.

Comment: Sorry, i was working on a JSFiddle sample and was planning to add it after. It's in the original post now

Comment: code must be **in the question** a simple fiddle link is *not* sufficient.

Comment: @Paulie_D Okay... Not seen that rule. It doesn't let you post a JSFiddle link if there are no code in the post but I had the offending code in the post